# Foreach inside a switch-statement

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

How can I enclose a `foreach`-loop inside a `switch`-statement?

I've got something like this (don't know if it's correct though):

```
    $activiteiten = array(2,9,11);

    switch ($list_day) { 
            case $today : 
                $calendar.= '<td class="today">';
                break;

             foreach ($activiteiten as &$value) {
                case $value : 
                $calendar .= '<td class="date_has_event">';
                break;
             }

            default : 
                $calendar .= '<td>';
        }
```

The error I get is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CASE in ..."

Comment: the `break;` command exits the current `case` so try removing that first.. :)

Comment: I believe you need a different approach here...

Comment: Nop, didn't work. I thought a `brake` was needed in a `switch`-statement?

Comment: You have too many levels of indirection. You have to write the code you want. You have merely written the code to write the code you want. You have to *make* the recipe, not eat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's your default case:

```
$activiteiten = array(2,9,11);

switch ($list_day)
{ 
    case $today:

        $calendar .= '<td class="today">';
        break;

    default:

         foreach ($activiteiten as $value)
         {
            if ($list_day === $value)
            {
                $calendar .= '<td class="date_has_event">';
                break 2; # !!
            }
         }

        $calendar .= '<td>';
}
```

But instead you could (should) use some logic first to get the `$class` and if it's still empty, create an empty `<TD>` element, if it's set, create a `<TD class="...">` element.

Comment: Actually, this is even better! Thanks hakre! Why is the '2' in `break 2;`?

Comment: `break 2;` means Exit the foreach  and switch. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not allow you to create case statements programmatically.

How about this:

```
$activiteiten = array(2,9,11);

if ($list_day == $today){
    $calendar.= '<td class="today">';
}elseif(in_array($list_day, $activiteiten)){
    $calendar .= '<td class="date_has_event">';
}else{
    $calendar .= '<td>';
}
```

Comment: Yup, did the trick. Thanks a lot!! (I needed to switch `$activiteiten` and `$list_day` though ;))

Answer (score 1):

Not possible this way. You may try something like

```
if (in_array($list_day, $activiteiten))
```

instead